# Is __TIME__ preprocessor macro guaranteed to be constant within a file?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Just out of curiosity I am wondering whether the value given by the standard `__TIME__` preprocessor macro can change within a single translation unit?

In other words, is `__TIME__` determined once during preprocessing and then fixed, or is it re-evaluated each time it is encountered?

If this is not specified by the C standard, is there a de facto standard behavior among the major implementations (gnu, clang, intel, msvc)?

Comment: See 6.10.8.1p1 It very likely means when the preprocessing _starts_. Anything else would be pretty useless.

Comment: I think the current version of GNU CPP establishes values for`__TIME__` and `__DATE__` at the same time, at the time either macro is first expanded.  I'm not 100% sure, but the scope of a particular set of values for these macros appears to be the allocated while the command line options are parsed, so essentially once per invocation.  GCC source is notoriously convoluted.

Comment: @NovaDenizen  a need for simultaneity of `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` is an excellent point!  Imagine if these 2 were not set at the same instant.  Else with a `__TIME__` of `00:00:00` the `__DATE__` could be yesterday or today.  The only sane functionality is a one-time setting of both values.

Comment: An extension of this question (or its consequences thereof) - in a multi-module project, compilation of modules may expand over a long period of time. If these macros appear in multiple modules, then the generated expansions are not in sync, even if it is guaranteed in a *specific* module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not rigorously specify the the " time of translation" is constant throughout a pre-processing/compilation.

My experience has been it is constant.  But since it is only to the second, a given compilation would need to cross a second boundary to differ.

> `__TIME__` The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character string literal of the form `"hh:mm:ss"` as in the time generated by the
>   `asctime` function. If the time of translation is not available, an
>   implementation-defined valid time shall be supplied. C11 §6.10.8.1 1
>
> The definitions for `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` when respectively, the date and
>   time of translation are not available (6.10.8.1).  (Informative) C11 §J.3.11 1

Comment: I doubt there is a de facto standard, yet that is only an opinion.  Yet I agree with [@Olaf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901990/is-time-preprocessor-macro-guaranteed-to-be-constant-within-a-file/36902152#comment61368099_36901990) that a single occurrence is reasonable.  Now the question is what is the use case where it makes a difference?

Comment: No use case that I can think of... just a curiosity.